# How to access optional paramaters in a view? Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

- How do I access the type of address and pass those details to the
  view?
- Because I would like to access the 2nd parameter to update
  the form to change the header to "billing address" or "shipping
  address" depending on what type it is?
- I have set up the optional parameter {type?} in the web.php, however, don't know how to access
  it in the AddressController function store?

// index.blade.php (view for AddressController@store)

```
<a href="{{ route('address.create', 'billing' ) }}" class="btn btn-success"> Add Billing Address </a>
<a href="{{ route('address.create', 'shipping' ) }}" class="btn btn-success"> Add Shipping Address </a>
```

// AddressController

```
public function create()
{
    return view('pages.address.create');
}
```

// web.php

```
Route::get('address/create/{type?}', 'AddressController@create')->name('address.create');
```

Expected results: 
Title: **Create Billing Address:** for url: ..address/create/billing
Title: **Create Shipping Address:** for url: ..address/create/shipping

---

Is it better to split into **BillingAddressController** and **ShippingAddressController**?

Comment: "Is it better to split into BillingAddressController and ShippingAddressController?" I guess: "no". Unless you've divided the addresses into seperate tables, but that's very uncommon.

Comment: @vanderbake Ok thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your controller:

```
public function create (Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->type;

    return view('pages.address.create', compact('type'));
}
```

In your view you can use the `$type` variable to set a hidden field or show/display fields depending on your application logic.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

From your view you can try it:

```
{{ Request::segment($i) }}
```

where $i is going to be the parameter number that you want from your route. In your case 2